# Parse a CSV File and Rename the columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a csv file which has spaces in the column names in the header record. The source system is unable to rename the fields before sending - so, we have to handle this at our end before ingestion.

The column-names (of the src csv file) will be stored in another file on S3 along with the column-name it has to be changed to. So the program has to be generic so that it can handle an arbitrary number of columns based on the config file.

Config File:

```
src_column-name        | target column-name
S.No                   | SNo
Count of lines visited | LinesVisited
Revenue                | RevenueGenerated
No. of clicks          | NumberofClicks
```

Hence, is there a way to read the config file line-by-line and rename the source column-names (Column# 1) as per the target column-name (Column# 2) and then read the data of the actual csv file with the new column-names and save it back to S3 as a csv file with a different name.

For e.g. -

Expected:

```
SNo | LinesVisited | RevenueGenerated | Numberofclicks
```

We can use Pyspark or Python. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**`Method-1:`**

You can create a schema and then read the csv file using the specified schema.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.read.option("schema", sch).option("header",True).csv()
```

---

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sch = StructType([StructField("sno", StringType(), True),StructField("Countoflinesvisited", StringType(), True), StructField("Revenue",StringType(), True),StructField("Noofclicks", StringType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([('','','','',)],sch)
df.show()
```

**`Method-2:`**
If you are not sure about the column names then replace the special characters by using `replace`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('','','','',)],['S.No','Count of lines visited','Revenue','No. of clicks'])
cols = [f.replace(' ','').replace('.','') for f in df.columns]
df.toDF(*cols).show()
#+---+-------------------+-------+----------+
#|SNo|Countoflinesvisited|Revenue|Noofclicks|
#+---+-------------------+-------+----------+
#|   |                   |       |          |
#+---+-------------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I have made some updates to the question. I am new to PySpark hence sorry for the update repeatedly. I need to read the config file and change the columns of the csv file as per the target column names mentioned and save it back to s3.. Thanks for helping out.